# Making DOM element inaccessible from searching

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom

I would want to make DOM element inaccessible by search into tree/array whatever it is.

Example code for overriding `getElementById`

```
var x = document.createElement("div");
x.id = "foo";
document.body.appendChild(x);
var doc = document.getElementById;
document.getElementById = function(a){
if(doc.call(document, a) === x) return null;
  return doc.call(document, a);
};
```

then `document.getElementById("foo")` returns `null` as expected.

I can override all the functions but there is too many possibilities to get an element, for example `document.body.childNodes[x]`

Is it possible to override prototype or maybe delete element from tree/array where search works but no from DOM?

Target browser is google-chrome.

Comment: What terrible thing are you adding to the page that you don't want people to find?

Comment: If it would be possible there is a lot of good things you can do.. not removeable add from userscripts for example. In general my script would be just more protected from user modifications..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution by myself, simply `<shadov>` element exactly does what I need.

```
var shadowEl = parentNode.createShadowRoot();
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/HTML/Element/shadow

But some overrides needed, for example:

```
Object.defineProperty(document.getElementById("foo"), 'shadowRoot', {
  get: function(){
    return null;
  },
  enumerable: false
});
```